# how do add 3 letters from a list to 3 input letters

Tags: python

this is what i have as of now but it does not work. i want to have 3 letters from the input and then add one of the random 3 letters from the list

```
#User Input
usernames = int(input("How Many Usernames Are To Be Generated?"))
for item in range(0,usernames):
    name = input("What Is The First Three Letters of The Pupils Name?")

import random
random = ["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]

final = (name + random)

print (final)
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: "it does not work" is not a description

Comment: changed description @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying something along the following lines:

```
import random

usernames = int(input("How Many Usernames Are To Be Generated?"))
names = []  # gotta collect the names
for item in range(usernames):
    names.append(input("What Is The First Three Letters of The Pupils Name?"))

suffixes = ["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]  # don't shadow 'random' module

for name in names:
    # append a random suffix to each name
    final = name + random.choice(suffixes)
    print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be done something like this :

```
import random
suffix = ["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]

#User Input
usernames = int(input("How Many Usernames Are To Be Generated?"))
for item in range(0,usernames):
    name = input("What Is The First Three Letters of The Pupils Name?")
    final = (name + random.choice(suffix))
    print (final)
```

This saves a list of suffixes using which names can be generated. 
The first input is taken from the user to know how many names are to be generated. For each name, the user enters a prefix. The prefix is added to a randomly chosen suffix and printed.

Answer (score 0):

well, I think the problem is that you are trying to add a list to a string. You have to select just one element using random.choice()

Try this:

```
usernames = int(input("How Many Usernames Are To Be Generated?"))
for item in range(0,usernames):
    name = input("What Is The First Three Letters of The Pupils Name?")

import random
rand_element = random.choice(["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"])

final = (name + rand_element)

print (final)
```